# get entries with same string of a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I need to get the values of the entries with the same string.
I need to find `campus0`, next make a foreach and get the `link0` text and link, and repeat. `for (n) campus campus_0, and for (n) link`.

I can not change my json to an multidimensional array because I am getting from another site.

***I am using angularjs***

Json example:

```
"campus_0_name": [
"Petone"
],
"campus_0_link_0_text": [
"Bachelor of Engineering Technology Degree (Level 7) "
],
"campus_0_link_0_url": [
"https://www.weltec.ac.nz/SUBJECTAREAS/EngineeringTechnology/BachelorofEngineeringTechnology/tabid/695/Default.aspx"
],
"campus_0_link_1_text": [
"New Zealand Diploma in Engineering (Level 6) "
],
"campus_0_link_1_url": [
"https://www.weltec.ac.nz/SUBJECTAREAS/Engineering/NewZealandDiplomainEngineeringLevel6Y1/tabid/1002/Default.aspx"
],
"campus_0_link_2_text": [
"Certificate in Foundation Studies (Level 3 and 4) - Engineering"
],
"campus_0_link_2_url": [
"https://www.weltec.ac.nz/SUBJECTAREAS/EngineeringTechnology/CertificateinFoundationStudiesEngineering/tabid/1253/Default.aspx"
],

"campus_1_link_0_text": [
"Bachelor of Engineering Technology Degree (Level 7) "
],
"campus_1_link_0_url": [
"https://www.weltec.ac.nz/SUBJECTAREAS/EngineeringTechnology/BachelorofEngineeringTechnology/tabid/695/Default.aspx"
],
"campus_1_link_1_text": [
"New Zealand Diploma in Engineering (Level 6) "
],
"campus_1_link_1_url": [
"https://www.weltec.ac.nz/SUBJECTAREAS/Engineering/NewZealandDiplomainEngineeringLevel6Y1/tabid/1002/Default.aspx"
],
"campus_1_link_2_text": [
"Certificate in Foundation Studies (Level 3 and 4) - Engineering"
],
"campus_1_link_2_url": [
"https://www.weltec.ac.nz/SUBJECTAREAS/EngineeringTechnology/CertificateinFoundationStudiesEngineering/tabid/1253/Default.aspx"
]
```

This is what I wish to accomplish.

```
<div class="campus_0">
    <dl class="link_0">
        <dt class="text">Bachelor of Engineering Technology Degree (Level 7)</dt>
        <dd class="url">"https://www.weltec.ac.nz/SUBJECTAREAS/EngineeringTechnology/BachelorofEngineeringTechnology/tabid/695/Default.aspx"</dd>
    </dl>

    <dl class="link_1">
        <dt class="text">Bachelor of Engineering Technology Degree (Level 7)</dt>
        <dd class="url">"https://www.weltec.ac.nz/SUBJECTAREAS/EngineeringTechnology/BachelorofEngineeringTechnology/tabid/695/Default.aspx"</dd>
    </dl>

    <dl class="link_2">
        <dt class="text">Bachelor of Engineering Technology Degree (Level 7)</dt>
        <dd class="url">"https://www.weltec.ac.nz/SUBJECTAREAS/EngineeringTechnology/BachelorofEngineeringTechnology/tabid/695/Default.aspx"</dd>
    </dl>

</div>


<div class="campus_1">
    <dl class="link_0">
        <dt class="text">Bachelor of Engineering Technology Degree (Level 7)</dt>
        <dd class="url">"https://www.weltec.ac.nz/SUBJECTAREAS/EngineeringTechnology/BachelorofEngineeringTechnology/tabid/695/Default.aspx"</dd>
    </dl>

    <dl class="link_1">
        <dt class="text">Bachelor of Engineering Technology Degree (Level 7)</dt>
        <dd class="url">"https://www.weltec.ac.nz/SUBJECTAREAS/EngineeringTechnology/BachelorofEngineeringTechnology/tabid/695/Default.aspx"</dd>
    </dl>

    <dl class="link_2">
        <dt class="text">Bachelor of Engineering Technology Degree (Level 7)</dt>
        <dd class="url">"https://www.weltec.ac.nz/SUBJECTAREAS/EngineeringTechnology/BachelorofEngineeringTechnology/tabid/695/Default.aspx"</dd>
    </dl>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the given data in the given format may be little difficult, so one way is to convert the data format to an easy one once it is received from the server like

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  var data = {
    "campus_0_name": [
      "Petone"
    ],
    "campus_0_link_0_text": [
      "Bachelor of Engineering Technology Degree (Level 7) "
    ],
    "campus_0_link_0_url": [
      "https://www.weltec.ac.nz/SUBJECTAREAS/EngineeringTechnology/BachelorofEngineeringTechnology/tabid/695/Default.aspx"
    ],
    "campus_0_link_1_text": [
      "New Zealand Diploma in Engineering (Level 6) "
    ],
    "campus_0_link_1_url": [
      "https://www.weltec.ac.nz/SUBJECTAREAS/Engineering/NewZealandDiplomainEngineeringLevel6Y1/tabid/1002/Default.aspx"
    ],
    "campus_0_link_2_text": [
      "Certificate in Foundation Studies (Level 3 and 4) - Engineering"
    ],
    "campus_0_link_2_url": [
      "https://www.weltec.ac.nz/SUBJECTAREAS/EngineeringTechnology/CertificateinFoundationStudiesEngineering/tabid/1253/Default.aspx"
    ],

    "campus_1_link_0_text": [
      "Bachelor of Engineering Technology Degree (Level 7) "
    ],
    "campus_1_link_0_url": [
      "https://www.weltec.ac.nz/SUBJECTAREAS/EngineeringTechnology/BachelorofEngineeringTechnology/tabid/695/Default.aspx"
    ],
    "campus_1_link_1_text": [
      "New Zealand Diploma in Engineering (Level 6) "
    ],
    "campus_1_link_1_url": [
      "https://www.weltec.ac.nz/SUBJECTAREAS/Engineering/NewZealandDiplomainEngineeringLevel6Y1/tabid/1002/Default.aspx"
    ],
    "campus_1_link_2_text": [
      "Certificate in Foundation Studies (Level 3 and 4) - Engineering"
    ],
    "campus_1_link_2_url": [
      "https://www.weltec.ac.nz/SUBJECTAREAS/EngineeringTechnology/CertificateinFoundationStudiesEngineering/tabid/1253/Default.aspx"
    ]
  };

  var list = [];
  angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
    var match = key.match(/campus_(\d+)_link_(\d+)_(\w+)/);
    if (match) {
      var sublist = list[match[1]] || (list[match[1]] = []);
      var obj = sublist[match[2]] || (sublist[match[2]] = {});
      obj[match[3]] = value;
    }
  });

  $scope.list = list;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <div ng-repeat="array in list track by $index" class="campus_{{$index}}">
    <dl ng-repeat="obj in array track by $index" class="link_{{$index}}">
      <dt class="text">{{obj.text}}</dt>
      <dd class="url">"{{obj.url}}"</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi Arun , thanks for your answer, just i have a question, what mind the strings (\d+) (\w+), it is a special code? it is possible do exactly same but with a comun code? –  user1842369 just now   edit

Comment: @user1842369 that is very common code.... those are [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Thanks,  can i pass any value? for example now i undestand that u use d+ for the numbers and w for the words, and after that you create the new array...  is  it that right?